# Django: Implementing a nested, reusable component design

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm working on a big social networking app in Django where I expect to use certain front-end components many times, and often with functionality designed in such a way that custom components contain other custom components, which might contain yet smaller subcomponents (ad infinitum).  All of these components are typically dynamic generated.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to architect this in the Django framework, such that my components are easy to maintain and have clear programming interfaces.  Relying heavily on global context would seem to be the opposite of this, however, I can see advantages in avoiding redundant queries by doing them all at once in the view.

Custom inclusion template tags seem like a good fit for implementing components, but I'm wondering, do highly nested template tags can create performance issues, or does the parsing architecture prevent this?  What is the best way of making it self-documenting at the view level what context is needed to render the main page template, custom tags and all?  I'm imagining it to be a minor nightmare to try to properly maintain the code to set up the template context.  Lastly, what is the best way to maintain the CSS for these components?

Feel free to suggest other recommended approaches for creating a nested-component design.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I've decided on so far is to go ahead with using an inclusion tag library as my set of reusable components.  I'm sticking as much as possible to setting up all queries in my view code, and passing them in pre-setup in my context--no functions that generate new queries in templates or tag library code.  The inclusion templates contain all of the markup for the item, and the styles go into the main site stylesheet, keeping my classes as generic and reusable as possible, following the guidelines of [SMACSS](https://smacss.com/).  I refactor components into inclusion tags only as DRY requires.

I initially made my inclusion tag functions explicitly take the parameters used by the tag template, such that:

**Page template**

```
<div>{% my_tag param1 param2 %}</div>
```

**Tag library**

```
@register.inclusion_tag('myapp/tagtemplates/my_tag.html')
def my_tag(param1, param2):
    return {'param1': param1, 'param2': param2}
```

**my_tag.html**

```
<div>Blah: {{ param1 }}</div>
<div>Blip: {{ param2 }}</div>
```

...and obviously the view sets up the context.

But I decided instead to use the `takes_context` parameter to avoid explicitly defining the parameters in the tag library.  Too much repetition for not enough payoff in documentation.  So far, my components are simple enough that the dependencies are pretty clear from inspection of the tag template.  I worry that this might not be acceptable with complicated nested components, but I can always make my tag library functions verbose, where they need to be.

I'm not entirely pleased with this setup from a maintenance standpoint.  I don't like that I will have to manually track what context data is no longer needed.  I don't like the fact that my CSS classes will have to be carefully named to avoid clashes.

I am still open to new solutions, because I'm not sure that what I've decided really is a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

It is an interesting problem. Ideally you should pull all the components from database before rendering. But looking at hierarchy, making template tags makes sense. These template tag will pull appropriate data. Assume for the purpose of this problem that database query gets cached due to search locality.

Comment: It seems like an extremely common problem to me, which is why I'm finding it a bit weird that neither the manual, nor any resources I've found, nor any answers I've received (until yours), directly address the issues of making an architecture that is modular on a component level and maintainable.  Maybe people aren't really using Django for this.  But even if that's the case, I would expect the basic issue to exist in any MVC framework.